# Atom wrong autocomplete

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

Been using atom a lot but have started getting this annoying autocomplete issue today, in javascript when I do a promise like following, it tries to autocomplete when i just want a new line.

Example:
`var promise = proCol.orderBy('order').get().then(query => {$sceDelegate})`

I don't think I have ever use `$sceDelegate` before

Seems to be when I type `=> {}` it does to complete it when I always want a new line and not some odd variables it thinks I want. Finding it extremely annoying to when I am coding all day and this happens very often.

If anyone could help me out I would it would be amazing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get the same thing. It was from a recent package that I installed called Angularjs. $sceDelegate is Angular so I disabled the package for now and now it doesn't annoy me either. Check to see if you have an AngularJS package installed.